# Django import export how to read import this file

Tags: django, django-import-export

Here is a picture of the import file that is to be imported

[image: x]

I want to read the course column but when I exclude the group column, it shows all the columns are being skipped. How can I import this file?

This is the code currently:

```
class courseAttendanceResource(resources.ModelResource):
Student_ID = Field(attribute='Student_ID', column_name='Student ID')
Username = Field(attribute='Username', column_name='Username')
ID_number = Field(attribute='ID_number', column_name='ID number')
Institution = Field(attribute='Institution', column_name='Institution')
Department = Field(attribute='Department', column_name='Department')
Surname = Field(attribute='Surname', column_name='Surname')
First_name = Field(attribute='First_name', column_name='First name')
Groups = Field(attribute='Groups', column_name='Groups')
P = Field(attribute='P', column_name='P')
L = Field(attribute='L', column_name='L')
E = Field(attribute='E', column_name='E')
A = Field(attribute='A', column_name='A')
Taken_sessions = Field(attribute='Taken_sessions', column_name='Taken sessions')
Points = Field(attribute='Points', column_name='Points')
Percentage = Field(attribute='Percentage', column_name='Percentage')

def get_export_headers(self):
    headers = super().get_export_headers()
    for i, h in enumerate(headers):
        if h == 'Student ID':
            headers[i] = 'Student_ID'
        if h == 'Username':
            headers[i] = 'Username'
        if h == 'ID number':
            headers[i] = 'ID_number'
        if h == 'Institution':
            headers[i] = 'Institution'
        if h == 'Department':
            headers[i] = 'Department'
        if h == 'Surname':
            headers[i] = 'Surname'
        if h == 'First name':
            headers[i] = 'First_name'
        if h == 'Groups':
            headers[i] = 'Groups'
        if h == 'P':
            headers[i] = 'P'
        if h == 'L':
            headers[i] = 'L'
        if h == 'E':
            headers[i] = 'E'
        if h == 'A':
            headers[i] = 'A'
        if h == 'Taken sessions':
            headers[i] = 'Taken_sessions'
        if h == 'Points':
            headers[i] = 'Points'
        if h == 'Percentage':
            headers[i] = 'Percentage'
    return headers

class Meta:
    model = courseAttendance

    with open('/tmp/rows.csv') as csvfile:
        # skip the first 3 lines
        [next(csvfile, None) for i in range(3)]

        # now load the dataset
        ds = tablib.Dataset()
        ds.csv = csvfile.read()
        print(ds)
        dataset = ds
        result = resource.import_data(dataset)
    import_id_fields = ('Student_ID',)
    exclude = ('Course', 'Group',)
    fields = ('Student_ID', 'Username', 'ID_number', 'Institution', 'Department', 'Surname', 'First_name', 'Groups',
              'P', 'L', 'E', 'A', 'Taken_sessions', 'Points', 'Percentage',)
    #export_order = ('Student_ID', 'Username', 'ID_number', 'Institution', 'Department', 'Surname','First_name', 'Groups', 'P', 'L', 'E', 'A','Taken_sessions', 'Points', 'Percentage')
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
```

I need to read the course and exclude the group column. After that i want to read the rest of the columns. I applied your answer but it gives me an error at

```
result = resource.import_data(dataset)
```

Comment: please attach your code with your question

Comment: Are you importing with code or using the Admin console?

Comment: I have updated the code hope it clears things more.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Dataset](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#importing-data) before you call `import_data()`:

Given a csv file:

```sh
Course
Group

Student ID,Username
123,abc
```

```py
import tablib

with open('/tmp/rows.csv') as csvfile:
    # skip the first 3 lines
    [next(csvfile, None) for i in range(3)]

    # now load the dataset
    ds = tablib.Dataset()
    ds.csv = csvfile.read()
    print(ds)
```

Produces:

```
Student ID|Username
----------|--------
123       |abc
```

Once you have loaded your dataset, you can call the `import_data()` method:

```py
result = resource.import_data(dataset)
```

Comment: Does this require me to manually place the csv in the project directory? Im afraid im not allowed to do that. And sorry for not mentioning its an xlsx file. Plus i was getting an error at result = resource.import_data(dataset)

Comment: The file can be anywhere you like as long as it can be read from the running process.  xlsx is [supported by tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/#xlsx).  I cannot help with the error unless you give more details.